# Eclipse Console Output grouped by Classes

Tags: eclipse, plugins, logging, eclipse-plugin

Is there any plugin or way around to group the log traces from each classes. Basically, I am working on creating multiple processes, and want to view the logs from each classes once at a time.

I am trying to look for some way or the other, but couldnt do it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a Java project you can change the default `System.out` with [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) for a custom implementation which buffers the output per thread but using loggers (SLF4J + Logback for example) usually is better solution.
Logback also supports [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).